# Setting the alignment of a node without using BorderPane?

Tags: java, javafx

So I have a Text node which I want to position at the Top-Right side of the scene. Most methods state to use `BorderPane`, but in my case some of the other nodes in my scene are using `Pane`which is also my root pane, so the obvious workaround is to add the nodes you want to the `BorderPane` and add the `BorderPane` to the root `Pane`.

However `BorderPane` does not seem to be compatible with the `Pane`. That is, all the nodes of the `BorderPane` won't be shown. Also positioning the nodes based on their translate X and Y are not supported in `BorderPane` as well.(i.e. setLayoutX() does not work.) Because of this I cannot even make my root `Pane` to `BorderPane`.

Here is what I've tried:

```java
public class foo {
    private Pane root = new Pane();
    private BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    private Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1366, 768);

    public foo(){
        Text text1 = new Text("test1");
        text1.setLayoutX(11); // Ignore this if you want.
        test1.setLayoutY(11);

        Text text2 = new Text("test2");

        root.getChildren().add(test1);
        borderPane.setRight(text2);
        root.getChildren().add(borderPane);

        // Display the scene on a stage.
    }
}
```

Here only `test1` is shown and `test2` is not seen.
Is there a way I can position this text on the RIGHT TOP side of the screen **without** using `BorderPane`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pane` just resizes the children to the preferred size. Since you only place the `Text` node as child of the `BorderPane`, its preferred size is the size of the child.

In this case I recommend using a different layout, e.g.

#### StackPane

This allows you set the alignment of a node within the layout using `StackPane.setAlignment(child, newAlignment);`. The drawback is that setting an absolute position requires you to either make the child unmanaged (with some side effects) or specifying 4 values (an `Insets` instance) as margin.

```
Text text1 = new Text("test1");
StackPane.setMargin(text1, new Insets(11, 0, 0, 11));
StackPane.setAlignment(text1, Pos.TOP_LEFT);

Text text2 = new Text("test2");
StackPane.setAlignment(text2, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);

root = new StackPane(text1, text2);
```

#### AnchorPane

This does not allow for center alignments, but it allows you to set absolute positions using `layoutX` and `layoutY` just the way you'd do in a `Pane`. You can set anchor properties to specify the distance of a child from the top, left, right and/or bottom:

```
Text text1 = new Text("test1");
text1.setLayoutX(11);
text1.setLayoutY(11);

Text text2 = new Text("test2");
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(text2, 0d);
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(text2, 0d);

root = new AnchorPane(text1, text2);
```

Comment: I cannot seem to get it to work. Can you include the root you used, etc in your code snippet? Also can I add the StackPane to my Pane? StackPane contains the text I want aligned and Pane contains all the other stuff. So that I can just add the StackPane to my root Pane. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use `Pane` as ancestor of the node you want to align right (unless you want the layout not to be responsive or use bindings). Assuming `text1` is the node you want to be positioned absolutely and `text2` the node to be aligned to the left the values assigned to the `root` variable in the code snippets are supposed to replace the root in your code; they should be used as root of the scene. You could still add a `Pane` as child instead of adding e.g. `text1` directly...